# Bootstrap cards underneath each other but the distance between them is way too big

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a quite simple webpage and it has 6 of those Bootstrap cards, 3 in a row and then it should have 3 below that. For some reason it puts an enormous gap between the first 2 cards, but not on the third one.

Here is how it looks right now (I've zoomed out so all cards are visible): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCAJX.jpg

and here is my code for the cards:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card w-100" style="width: 32rem; height: auto;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/zuivering.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">Water zuivering</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
             <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 32rem; height: auto;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/recycle.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">Recyclen van restafval</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
            <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->  
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 32rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
            <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>





<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 32rem;">
        <br>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX 11111</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
            <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 32rem;">
        <br>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX 22222</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
            <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 32rem;">
        <br>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX 33333</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
             <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you're applying additional CSS. In Bootstrap you very rarely have to add any CSS when it comes to widths, paddings or margins. This can all be done in your HTML.

To start with, pretty much remove all CSS including width and height and see what it looks like. You might also find it handy to put your first 3 boxes inside a `<div class="row">` then a second Row for the next 3 boxes and so on.

Comment: Eyy, thank you man! This worked like a charm. I deleted all CSS first and then added the <div class="row"> tags to both set of cards. This placed them directly under each other and from there I could just re-add the CSS width code I had, to make it the right size. Can't thank you enough for the quick and easy fix!!

Comment: You're welcome. It looks like your CSS wasn't having a negative effect as it turns out but the Row's changed everything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're wrapping all the code you pasted here inside a

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- your cards here -->
</div>
```

you need to remove your inline styles. That includes both your `width: 32rem` and your `height: auto` (which you for some reason only have on **some** of your cards?

When you use the row/col logic from bootstrap you should not declare the width, as that is supposed to b 4/12 of your grid. Defining a width will break that.

I would furthermore advise you to place that type of code (height, width etc.) into a .css file, so you can change the values in one place instead of doing it on every card.

Comment: But the width changes the width of those cards to the size i want. Removing that styling just makes the cards bigger and doesn't fix my issue

Comment: @user16935420 having a fixed width style like that, will probably work on your screen, but will break on almost any other screen. And the cards got bigger because you did not include the `div.row`

Answer (score 0):

You commented out your closing `<p>` tag here:

```
<p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
                     <!-- enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p> -->
```

This looks right after I removed the errant `w-100` which conflicted with your `width: 32rem` inline style (I removed all of those). I also added the obligatory `.container` and `.row` divs which I assume you just didn't include in your question.

See the snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/zuivering.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">Water zuivering</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/recycle.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">Recyclen van restafval</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <br>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX 11111</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <br>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/duurzaamheid/blauw.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px;">XXXXX XXXXX 22222</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The tag is closed right under that line

Comment: @idkwhatsgoingon - Not on the last card.

Comment: I did not see that. Didn't fix my question, but thanks anyway!